# C# - Structured splitting of a txt-file

Tags: c#, split, key

I have a txt-file with logs in it. they are separated by "\n\n"'s...
Every log includes key-value data:

```
Date: 2011/12/13 13:11:00
SeqNum: 332
LoggedBy: Admin

Raw Data:
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 0c 4d 00 00 08 00 22 03
```

Which splitting method is the best for this example?

I tried to create an array with logs in it. But what next? Switch case?

Comment: Splitting isn't a good candidate here. Use a regular expression to capture data according to the specific format used here (ie. *key: value*). You may need a special case for the Raw Data section.

Comment: Do you think i should split the lines and after that use a Regex for the key-value-pair?

Comment: No, I don't think you should split them at all. This is not a good fit for a split since you don't have delimited data.

Answer (score 1):

With file.ReadLines() you already get a line splitted iterator.

I suggest iterating through these lines, checking when a date is found (you can use line.Split(':') for that. Then read the sonsecutive header lines.

For the raw data you can use line.Split(' ') to split all the hexadecimal values.

For converting the date string into a date, see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14743/Easy-String-to-DateTime-DateTime-to-String-and-For

Comment: I've been trying to split with ':' but doesn't work for date at example.

Comment: You can use a Date method to parse it from a string to a date (I'm not sure which one), but you shouldn't split it into substrings. I changed the answer.

Comment: Yes i know. But this date includes ':' too.

Comment: You can also search for a string starting with 'Date' ... and then you split at the hardcoded position 5.

Comment: The pattern "(.)+:(.)+" works, but I get matches like "Date/Time: 2012/12/12". But I need only the value like "2012/12/12".

Comment: "Date: 2011/12/13 13:11:00".split(' ')[1] gives "2011/12/13"

Comment: `if (line.StartsWith("Date:")) date = DateTime.Parse(line.Substring(6));`